# Jetson Xavier and 16 12MP cameras

Tags: encoding, nvidia

I recently saw the Jetson Xavier from NVIDIA (https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-xavier-faq).

I need to connect 16 12MP cameras like this one: https://www.baumer.com/it/en/product-overview/image-processing-identification/industrial-cameras/lx-series/10-gige-interface/vlxt-123c-i/p/38561.

I have 2 questions:
1) can the interface provided manage at least 8 of them? These are the specs:
- 16x CSI-2 Lanes (40 Gbps in D-PHY V1.2 or 109 Gbps in CPHY v1.1)
- 8x SLVS-EC lanes (up to 18.4 Gbps)

2) Xavier boasts (2x) 4Kp60 | HEVC video decoding. 4k is too little for 12MP...can I split the 8 cameras video stream in 2, and encode the upper and lower part of the images in 2 separate videos, leveraging the HW encoder? Can it encode 16 video streams (2x8) at the same time?

Thank you!

Comment: Were you able to pull in the streams of 16 cameras on Xavier? What was the max number of streams you could acheive?

Comment: We did not try as we decided for a non-embedded solution.